# Convert bin2hex() from php to python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I wanted to convert from PHP to Python:

```
bin2hex(random_bytes(8))
```

But i got an error using:
**hex(os.urandom(8))**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`binascii.hexlify()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.hexlify) or `bytes.hex()` to convert from bytes to hexadecimal:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> import os
>>> binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(8))
b'1f981c91062fa8bb'
>>> os.urandom(8).hex()
'194adba04509969e'
```